# Given: $C=10$, $C^a=3$, $C^b=5$, how to solve $C^{2a-b+1}$.

Tags: exponentiation

Given: $C=10$, $C^a=3$, $C^b=5$, how to solve $C^{2a-b+1}$.

I would be very grateful if somebody show me how to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It’s simply a matter of using the [laws of exponents](http://oakroadsystems.com/math/expolaws.htm):

$$\begin{align*}
C^{2a-b+1}&=C^{2a}\cdot C^{-b}\cdot C^1\\\\
&=(C^a)^2\cdot\frac1{C^b}\cdot C\\\\
&=3^2\cdot\frac15\cdot 10\\\\
&=9\cdot 2\\\\
&=18\;.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's like $C^a \cdot (C^a/C^b)\cdot C = 3 \cdot(3/5)\cdot 10 = 90/5 = 18$

I hope you understand

Comment: this answer would be useful if you used latex

Answer (score 0):

We are given that $C = 10, C^a = 3, C^b = 5$, and we want to evaluate $C^{2a - b + 1}$.

Then this becomes an exercise in rewriting. Note that $C^{2a - b + 1} = \dfrac{C \cdot (C^{a})^2}{C^b}$, and then you can substitute naively.